# Does anyone have an idea how to make this so that it will use yield? (python)

Tags: python

```
def MultiplicationTable():
    on = True
    while on:
        print("\nType 101 to exit application.")
        number = int(input("What table is to be printed out (1-10)? "))
        if 0 < number < 11:
            print("Multiplication table of: ", number)
            for mul in range(1, 11):
                print("{0} * {1} = {2}".format(number, mul, (number * mul)))
        elif number < 0:
            print("Your Input is a negative number!")
        elif number == 0:
            print("Your input is zero, any number multiplied to zero is also zero.")
        elif number == 101:
            print("Quitting application...")
            on = False
        else:
            print("Your Input is greater than 10!")


MultiplicationTable()
```

I've tried putting yield, but I cannot make it work.

The output should be like this:

What table is to be printed out (1-10)? 1

Multiplication table of:  1

1 * 1 = 1

1 * 2 = 2

1 * 3 = 3

1 * 4 = 4

1 * 5 = 5

1 * 6 = 6

1 * 7 = 7

1 * 8 = 8

1 * 9 = 9

1 * 10 = 10

Comment: yield what? what is it you're trying to do

Comment: Output should be generated using a Generator Expression but you will be displaying the complete equation.

Comment: Instead of printing the output, just yield it as a string.. Your function will then return a generator which you can exhaust in e.g. a loop.

Comment: I've tried using yield instead of printing it out but there is no output at all. Maybe I forgot something or missed something. I am still a beginner so yeah, haha.

Comment: @KaisenPaulGuinaban I suggest you study generators/yield then. When you use yield, your function returns a `generator`, which you can then iterate. E.g. `for g in MultiplicationTable(): print(g)`

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll review it once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? If you have to use `yield` in this program. But seem no meaning.

```
 def MultiplicationTable():
     on = True
     while on:
         print("\nType 101 to exit application.")
         number = int(input("What table is to be printed out (1-10)? "))
         if 0 < number < 11:
             print("Multiplication table of: ", number)
             for line in gen_multi_table(number):
                 print(line)
         elif number < 0:
             print("Your Input is a negative number!")
         elif number == 0:
             print("Your input is zero, any number multiplied to zero is also zero.")
         elif number == 101:
             print("Quitting application...")
             on = False
         else:
             print("Your Input is greater than 10!")


 def gen_multi_table(number):
     for mul in range(1, 11):
         yield "{0} * {1} = {2}".format(number, mul, (number * mul))


 MultiplicationTable()
```

Answer (score 0):

The yield statement just suspends function’s execution and sends a value back to the caller, but retains enough state to enable function to resume where it is left off. When resumed, the function continues execution immediately after the last yield run.

```
def MultiplicationTable():
    on = True
    while on:
        yield("\nType 101 to exit application.")
        number = int(input("What table is to be printed out (1-10)? "))
        if 0 < number < 11:
            yield "Multiplication table of: "+str(number)
            for mul in range(1, 11):
                yield("{0} * {1} = {2}".format(number, mul, (number * mul)))
            break
        elif number < 0:
            yield("Your Input is a negative number!")
        elif number == 0:
            yield("Your input is zero, any number multiplied to zero is also zero.")
        elif number == 101:
            yield("Quitting application...")
            on = False
        else:
            yield("Your Input is greater than 10!")


for i in MultiplicationTable():
    print(i)
```

for any reference : [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/)